# android: IPC remove listener

Tags: android, service, ipc

I used this [tutorial](http://mindtherobot.com/blog/37/android-architecture-tutorial-developing-an-app-with-a-background-service-using-ipc/) to create my own :remote service. It works, but with one problem: I can't remove listener.
The trace is:

```
onServiceConnected add listener: net.ServiceGP$1@44930168
```

(from my main activity, when I do the following:

```
startService(i);
bindService(i, serviceConnection, 0);
```

Then form the service:

```
Adding new listener [net.bgtask.ServiceListener$Stub$Proxy@44916d30]... new listener size = 1
```

Then I press back button and:

```
onDestroy of main activity, removing listener: net.ServiceGP$1@44930168
```

And form the service:

```
Removing listener   [net.bgtask.ServiceListener$Stub$Proxy@44917440]... new listener size = 1
```

Weird...In activity I have the same object, but in the service different ones.
WHY so?

Answer (score 6):

Problem in this example (compare link) is that a list is used for the listener collection

```
private List<TweetCollectorListener> listeners = new ArrayList<TweetCollectorListener>();
```

instead of

```
private RemoteCallbackList<TweetCollectorListener> listeners = new RemoteCallbackList<TweetCollectorListener>();
```

with the corresponding

```
(1) listeners.register(listener);
(2) listeners.unregister(listener);
```

instead of

```
(1) listeners.add(listener);
(2) listeners.remove(listener);
```

The argument (seem to me) not to be reference to the same Listener, but RemoteCallbackList handles this problem.